# NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML Template

Tags: pdf, netsuite

I would like to custom Journal Entry PDF/HTML Template. However, Created by (createby) shows nothing in the output. Any step i miss? as I cannot find this field in the field picker [image]

Any one can tell me how to do it ?
Thanks

```
<body>
<table><tr>
<td>${companyInformation.companyName}<br />${companyInformation.addressText}</td>
<td>${record@title}</span><br /><span class="number">#${record.tranid}</span>
  <br />Created date: ${record.trandate}
  <br />Created by: ${record.createdby}
  <br />Approved date:
  <br />Approved by: ${record.nextapprover}
 </td>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a field that exists on most transactions.

On some projects I've created this as a custom field and populated it with a scripted Before Submit User Event.